# Why use a ConcurrentQueue in this case?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am looking at the [Roslyn September 2012 CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) with Reflector, and I noticed that the SlidingTextWindow class has the following:

```
internal sealed class SlidingTextWindow : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<char[]> arrayPool = new ConcurrentQueue<char[]>();
    private int basis;
    private readonly LexerBaseCache cache;
    private char[] characterWindow;
    private int characterWindowCount;
    private int characterWindowStart;
    private int offset;
    private readonly IText text;
    private readonly int textEnd;

    public SlidingTextWindow(IText text, LexerBaseCache cache)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.basis = 0;
        this.characterWindowStart = 0;
        this.offset = 0;
        this.textEnd = text.Length;
        this.cache = cache;
        if (!arrayPool.TryDequeue(out this.characterWindow))
        {
            this.characterWindow = new char[2048];
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        arrayPool.Enqueue(this.characterWindow);
        this.characterWindow = null;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I believe the purpose of this class is to provide fast access to substrings of the input text, by using `char[] characterWindow`, starting with 2048 characters at a time (although the `characterWindow` may grow). I believe this is because it is faster to take substrings of character arrays than of strings, as Eric Lippert [seems to indicate on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/07/19/strings-immutability-and-persistence.aspx).

The `SlidingTextWindow` class is instantiated each time the `Lexer` class is instantiated, which happens each call to `SyntaxTree.ParseText`.

I do not understand the purpose of the `arrayPool` field. Its only usage in this class is in the constructor and Dispose methods. When calling `SyntaxTree.ParseText`, there seems to be only one instance of the `Lexer` class and of the `SlidingTextWindow` class created. What advantage is gained by enqueuing the `characterWindow` when an instance is disposed and by trying to dequeue a `characterWindow` when an instance is created?

Perhaps somebody from the Roslyn team could help me understand this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The advantage is that collection pressure is reduced, which has a positive effect on overall performance.

The .NET garbage collector is of course a general-purpose garbage collector. The allocation and object lifetime patterns of a compiler and IDE are quite different than those of your average line-of-business application, and they tend to stress the GC in unusual ways.

If you look throughout Roslyn there are many places where small arrays are cached and re-used later rather than allowing the GC to identify them as short-lived trash and reclaim them immediately. Empirical experiments show that this gives a measurable improvement in performance.

I don't recommend doing so in your own application unless your profiling indicates that you have a measurable performance problem gated on collection pressure. For the vast majority of applications the GC is very well tuned, and the benefit of a pooling strategy is not worth the considerable costs.

Comment: Is the caching of small arrays done for the primary purpose of decreasing memory or increasing speed (or both)? Is is the case that with so many arrays necessary for a compiler/IDE, creating a new array each time would take up a lot of memory? Or would there be a speed increase by using a thread-safe queue and having multiple threads act on the arrays?

Comment: Primarily speed and responsiveness. The GC is interesting when it comes to performance -- it makes allocating memory almost free, but you pay the cost later when the GC has to run. And in some cases, that GC has a noticeable impact on typing if it were to happen to run just as you type a character in the editor while writing code and it wasn't able to do a completely concurrent GC.

I do want to highlight what Eric mentioned -- we only do this when we see that particular allocation coming up on profiles. We don't do things like this until we know it's a specific problem in a specific location.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Any specific reason for picking `ConcurrentQueue` instead of `ConcurrentBag`?

Comment: ConcurrentBag is optimized for multiple threads inserting objects, like when you're doing a fork-join pattern with multiple threads producing something. It's actually fairly heavyweight when you need a small list of objects. There were also bugs in earlier versions that caused memory leaks, it's possible this code was written when that was still the case.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: Thanks for following up Jason; awesome comments.